# How to map query parameter 'action' in ASP.NET route to the method of my method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my controller, I have setup Route like

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Route("test")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Test(string action = "")
```

When I load http://localhost/test?action=abc, I see my method gets called, but the value of 'action' equals to 'Test' instead of 'abc'

From here, it seems like the word 'action' is reserved for mapping.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

But how can I change it so that i can use 'action' as my query parameter?

Comment: Seems like you could simply change your 'action' parameter to something else like 'action2'

Comment: do you have any default route ? can you post it here please.

Comment: I can't change my 'action' parameter due to requirement. And I don't have any default rote.